# React - checkbox not update when multiple unselect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I click the + button to expand the group and click the checkbox of group 1, it executes as expected.
But the problem is, 
If I click the checkbox of group 1 first and then expand the group by clicking + button,
It shows all user clicked which is correct, if I clicked the checkbox of group 1 again, 
the checkbox of group 1 become unchecked, but the checkboxes of users do not get unchecked.

**Reproduce step:
refresh the page > Click group 1 checkbox > click + to expand > click group 1 checkbox again > then you'll see user checkbox do not become unselected**

SandBox Link below:
https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-antonelli-gl9rm

[image]
after Unselecting group 1, 2 checkboxes of users do not become unselected:
[image]

Comment: I appreciate your effort. Could you delete things in your code that is beyond the scope of the question? Seems too verbose.

Comment: I just simplify the code. Appreciate if you can take a look.

Comment: you have to uncheck them manually by your codes.

Comment: You should use a nested data structure to represent your state. The problem is your `Group 1` has no idea how its children data. Your component should basically be `NestedCheckbox`.

Comment: Can you explain more of how to use nested data structure to represent the state? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `isExist` method returns `undefined` instead of `false`, fix it to return always either `true`/`false`.

```js
isExist = (id, group) => {
    if (!this.props.selected) {
      console.log("selected = null");
      return false;
    }

    return (
      this.props.selected.find((ele) => ele.id === group + id) !== undefined
    );
  };
```

This way you don't have to manually convert its return value to `boolean` using `!!`.

I suggest to also refactor your `handleSelected` method to

```js
handleSelected = async (e) => {
  const { selected } = this.state;

  if (e.target.checked) {
    let temp = { id: e.target.id, name: e.target.name };
    return this.setState({ selected: [...selected, temp] });
  }

  this.setState({
    selected: selected.filter(({ id }) => id !== e.target.id)
  });
};
```

[image: Edit distracted-hoover-ts7nr]

Comment: Thanks for your answer first. Mulitple select/unselect work now, but you can try below:
Refresh > click + to expand > the group member cannot be selected

Comment: Ohhhh. wait give me a minute to debug.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are experiencing is a result of a problem in the first render - as you can see - you have "undefined Contact". You need to solve this issue, and then the grouping will work as you desire.

Comment: Also, Clicking the + button first should have same effect(Create a group member list) as clicking the group checkbox first.

Comment: And I want to get the group member list when I click the clickbox/expand if the group member list is undefined.